# I am having compilation problems with a jsp code that is saying== operator is undefined for argument int,null

Tags: java, jsp

here is the jsp code

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%=header.getIdSysImpHeader()==null)?"":header.getIdSysImpHeader()%>" id="headerPkId" name="headerPkId"/>
```

when doing this the compiler is giving me this error:

```
The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null
```

Comment: In addition to answer(s), you have an extra parenthesis here `header.getIdSysImpHeader()==null)?`

Comment: Is it your original code because it contains one extra `)` before `?`

Answer (score 0):

An int cannot be null, since it's a primitive value. I'm assuming `header.getIdSysImpHeader()` returns an int. That's the cause of your error.